# Как совместить apache для одних сайтов и nginx - для других?

Tags: apache, nginx, веб-сервер

При запуске PHP файлов появляется `502` ошибка при работающем HTML. Почему так происходит и как это исправить?

Apache я перебросил на порт `8080`.

Файл **/etc/nginx/nginx.conf**:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
  worker_connections 768;
  # multi_accept on;
}

http {

  ##
  # Basic Settings
  ##

  sendfile on;
  tcp_nopush on;
  tcp_nodelay on;
  keepalive_timeout 65;
  types_hash_max_size 2048;
  # server_tokens off;

  # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
  # server_name_in_redirect off;

  include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
  default_type application/octet-stream;

  ##
  # SSL Settings
  ##

  ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

  ##
  # Logging Settings
  ##

  access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

  ##
  # Gzip Settings
  ##

  gzip on;

  include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
  include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

Файл **/etc/nginx/_location.php**:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
try_files $fastcgi_script_name =404;
fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
fastcgi_index index.php;
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $htdocs$fastcgi_script_name;
include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
fastcgi_read_timeout 6000;
}
```

Файл **/etc/nginx/sites-available/php.x**:

```
server {
listen 80;
listen [::]:80;
charset utf-8;
server_name php.x;
set $yii_bootstrap "index.php";

access_log /var/log/nginx/php.x-access.log;
error_log /var/log/nginx/php.x-error.log;
root /var/www/php.x;
index $yii_bootstrap;

set $htdocs /var/www/php.x;

location / {

# Redirect everything that isn't real file to yii bootstrap file including arguments.
try_files $uri $uri/ /$yii_bootstrap?$args;
}

include /etc/nginx/_location_php;

}
```

Comment: /etc/php/7.2/fpm/pool.d/www.conf

Comment: Зачем так жить?..

Comment: так хочу чтоб был апач тоже

Comment: sudo service nginx reload
Job for nginx.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status nginx.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

Comment: @artoodetoo Вообще не советую использовать их одновременно, но если очень хочется 1. Наберите в консоле journalctl -xe и выложите лог ошибок. 2. Воспользуйтесь подробный гайдом. https://adw0rd.com/2009/3/27/nginx-and-apache-install/